# How do I delete all but duplicates from a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, duplicates

I have a list, let's say `X=[a,b,c,d,c,e,d]`, how can I delete one of each character so the only answer remains `X1=[c,d]`.

I have a bunch of lists with just alphabetical letters and I need a command which would delete every single letter once if list contains such and do nothing if there's none of that letter.

I have tried using `selectchk/3` for this but it only works for specific cases.

For instance if I have list `X=[a,b,c,d,d,e,e,f,f,g,h]`,
I can write `selectchk(d,X,X1), selectchk(e,X1,X2), selectchk(f,X2,X3)` etc.

As I said, this only works for specific case, however if I add general predicate, let's say I have `selectchk/3` for every single letter, but, for example, 
new list is `X1=[a,b,c,d,d]` and I use `selectchk(f,X,X3)`, 
command fails and doesn't name the next list `X3`, so the next command which checks for letter 'G' in list `X3` can't run since there's no such list. Is there a possibility to do OR command, if one fails?

```
X=[a,a,c,d,d,e]
```

`selectchk(a,X,X1)` OR (if there's no a) `append([],X,X1),selectchk(b,X1,X2)` OR (if there's no 'b'), `append([],X2,X3)` etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways one could do this. I think `selectchk/3` forms a good basis for a solution, which is really to "automate" what you attempted to do manually and use a recursion:

```
select_each_one(L, R) :-
    sort(L, PickList),
    select_each_one(L, PickList, R).
select_each_one(L, [H|T], R) :-
    selectchk(H, L, R1),
    select_each_one(R1, T, R).
select_each_one(L, [], L).
```

The `sort` provides a "picklist" containing just one of each of the elements in the original list. The `select_each_one/3` predicate then performs the `selectchk` with each of those elements on each iteration of the original list.

```
?- select_each_one([a,b,c,d,c,e,d], L).
L = [c, d] ;
false.

?- select_each_one([a,b,c,d,d,e,e,f,f,g,h], L).
L = [d, e, f] ;
false.
```

Another approach would be to copy the list over one element at a time, but track whether we've seen the element or not:

```
select_each_one(L, R) :-
    select_each_one(L, [], R).
select_each_one([H|T], Seen, R) :-
    (   member(H, Seen)
    ->  R = [H|R1], select_each_one(T, Seen, R1)
    ;   select_each_one(T, [H|Seen], R)
    ).
select_each_one([], _, []).
```

Comment: Thank you, it was really helpful for me, your solution was really easy to understand, I would still prefer first one.